# Material Button icon is not aligned properly when iconPadding is small

Tags: android, material-design, materialbutton

Create a `MaterialButton` with following attributes:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_star"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp" />
```

When updating the text to a short text, like "123", that does not change the width of the button, the icon does not align properly and may overlap the text. But if the text is long enough, like "123456789", to change the button's width, everything is alright.

[image: MaterialButton iconPadding bug]

It is more obvious when `iconPadding` is set to a small number like zero. In the gif above `iconPadding` is 2.

Android API version:
API 21, 26, 29

Material Library version:
com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha02

Am I doing something wrong? or this is a bug.
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
The issue is fixed ([see here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/b0f37007aa3cd00cc655439ff84484354c478a53)), waiting for the next release.

---

For anyone how has faced the same problem:
I reported this issue in github ([here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2553)) and it is marked as a bug.
I will update this answer if it is fixed in next versions.